# Selecting only the first row - compatiable with Mysql/SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, select

Is there a way to create a query to select only the first result that's compatible for both MySQL and SQL Server?

```
SELECT TOP 1 mycolumn, mycolumn2
FROM mytable
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

works for SQL Server.

but

```
SELECT mycolumn, mycolumn2
FROM mytable
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 1
```

works only for MySQL.

I'm not looking to download any PDO or database abstraction class - I'm wondering if there are SQL queries compatibility to both?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to create a query to select only the first result
>   that's compatible for both MySQL and SQL Server?

Short answer, no.

Long answer, not in any way efficiently. Somebody else suggested `WHERE id = MAX(id)`. That will work if `id` is the primary key. But not with the kind of optimization that the `TOP` and/or `LIMIT` features provide.

Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `TOP 1`, you can use `max() -- DESC` or `min() -- ASC`. But if you want get `TOP N`, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT mycolumn, mycolumn2
FROM mytable M1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM mytable M2
       WHERE M1.ID < M2.ID) < N  -- M1.ID < M2.ID: DESC, < N: TOP N
```